# I am having problems with my command line colors in Ubuntu 18.04 how can I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command

recently I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in VMware but I am having some problems with the command line. I especially like the color design of Ubuntu because the word colors helped me to discriminate the type of files.(Green is my favorite it is very pretty) However when I opened it today, the command line only showed white texts which is very frustrating. I tried to reset the settings but I don't know how. How can I reset the overall terminal style? I used basic settings but it didn't work.[image] What is the problem and how can I solve this? 
(the picture above is default state picture under is the issue that I'm encountering)

Answer (score 1):

Credit for this answer goes to @rubo77
Original answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/460493

To change your directory colors, open up your `~/.bashrc` file with your editor

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and make the following entry at the end of the file:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;35:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Some nice color choices (in this case `0;35` it is purple) are:

```
Blue = 34
Green = 32
Light Green = 1;32
Cyan = 36
Red = 31
Purple = 35
Brown = 33
Yellow = 1;33
Bold White = 1;37
Light Grey = 0;37
Black = 30
Dark Grey= 1;30
```

The first number is the style (1=bold), followed by a semicolon, and then the actual number of the color, possible styles (effects) are:

```
0   = default colour
1   = bold
4   = underlined
5   = flashing text (disabled on some terminals)
7   = reverse field (exchange foreground and background color)
8   = concealed (invisible)
```

The possible backgrounds:

```
40  = black background
41  = red background
42  = green background
43  = orange background
44  = blue background
45  = purple background
46  = cyan background
47  = grey background
100 = dark grey background
101 = light red background
102 = light green background
103 = yellow background
104 = light blue background
105 = light purple background
106 = turquoise background
107 = white background
```

All possible colors:

```
31  = red
32  = green
33  = orange
34  = blue
35  = purple
36  = cyan
37  = grey
90  = dark grey
91  = light red
92  = light green
93  = yellow
94  = light blue
95  = light purple
96  = turquoise
97  = white
```

These can even be combined, so that a parameter like:

```
di=1;4;31;42
```

in your `LS_COLORS` variable would make directories appear in bold underlined red text with a green background!

To test all these colors and styles in your terminal, you can use one of:

```
for i in 00{2..8} {0{3,4,9},10}{0..7}
do echo -e "$i \e[0;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m  \e[1;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m"
done

for i in 00{2..8} {0{3,4,9},10}{0..7}
do for j in 0 1
   do echo -e "$j;$i \e[$j;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m"
   done
done
```

You can also change other kinds of files when using the ls command by defining each kind with:

```
bd = (BLOCK, BLK)   Block device (buffered) special file
cd = (CHAR, CHR)    Character device (unbuffered) special file
di = (DIR)  Directory
do = (DOOR) [Door][1]
ex = (EXEC) Executable file (ie. has 'x' set in permissions)
fi = (FILE) Normal file
ln = (SYMLINK, LINK, LNK)   Symbolic link. If you set this to ‘target’ instead of a numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.
mi = (MISSING)  Non-existent file pointed to by a symbolic link (visible when you type ls -l)
no = (NORMAL, NORM) Normal (non-filename) text. Global default, although everything should be something
or = (ORPHAN)   Symbolic link pointing to an orphaned non-existent file
ow = (OTHER_WRITABLE)   Directory that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
pi = (FIFO, PIPE)   Named pipe (fifo file)
sg = (SETGID)   File that is setgid (g+s)
so = (SOCK) Socket file
st = (STICKY)   Directory with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
su = (SETUID)   File that is setuid (u+s)
tw = (STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE)    Directory that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
*.extension =   Every file using this extension e.g. *.rpm = files with the ending .rpm
```

A more complete list is available at [Bigsoft - Configuring LS_COLORS](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors).

On some distributions, you might also want to change the background color for `ow "(OTHER_WRITABLE) whose default is non-readable"` for example to non-bold blue text on green background.

You could use for instance `LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:di=1;33"` at the end of your `.bashrc` file, to get a nice readable bold orange text on black background.

After you alter your `.bashrc` file, to put the changes in effect you will have to restart your shell or run source `~/.bashrc`.

Note: You can combine more commands with a colon, for example

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;33:ln=36' ; export LS_COLORS; ls
```

Source:

```
[COLORS Lscolors - Linux StepByStep][2]
[Geek Gumbo - Changing the Directory Color in Bash][2]
```

Comment: Did you re-source the `.bashrc` file? Either run `source ~/.bashrc` after you make the change or close your terminal and re-open one.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using bash as your shell, this is usually set in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file. It looks like you're on two different machines in those images. You could copy between the two and that might help. For example:

```
scp gayan@V131:/home/gayan/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If it doesn't help, then your terminal app may not be configured for colours.

Comment: no, it is not 2 different machines. the upper picture is one that i captured in the internet. I have only one machine which is under